# angular $http post form data and key/value data

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, forms, http-post

Found a nice way of uploading files from angular to my node server to be processed by multer. The image upload and processing works perfectly, but I want to attach a key/value pair to this request. Unfortunately I do not know how to attach a key value pair to this request along with this form post!

```
var files = document.getElementById("change-pic-input").files;
var fd = new FormData();
              fd.append("file", files[0])
              uploadProfilePic(fd);

          });

          var uploadProfilePic = function(fd) {
              $http.post("/api/spot/pic/post", fd,{
                  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                  transformRequest: angular.identity
              }).then(
                      function successCallback(response) {
                        console.log("Success post image")
                      }, function errorCallback(response) {
                          console.log("fail post image")
                      });

          };
```

Would love to hear from an $http expert or someone smarter than me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can append another data into your formData variable. As follows;

```
fd.append('key', value);
```

Or if you want to send a json data with that request.

```
fd.append('jsonData', { key: value });
```

For back-end side;

As far as I know, you use req.files for reaching to your uploaded files. Now, I think you can use `req.body` for reaching to your other data inside of request. Like; `req.body.jsonData` or `req.body.key`.

Comment: Thanks for helping Ali. Unfortunately req.body and req.files is empty. I just want to send a number along with the image file. Perhaps the complexity lies with the Content-Type

Comment: Are you using body-parser for parsing body of requests? https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser If it doesn't exists, you can't see body property of req.

Comment: using express 3 but using the body-parser module. Yes. (`app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`)

Comment: I don't know why it isn't there. But I think you may check req variable with console.log(JSON.stringify(req)) and cmd/ctrl + f.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution that i found is to append parameters to the URL like

```
"/api/spot/pic/post?key=value"
```

and then on the server side

```
value = req.query.key
```

I would appreciate a better solution if possible. Thanks.